# Why was Rabbi Isaac Luria called "G-dly"?

Tags: names, shemos-sacred-names, arizal

R' Luria's acronym is the AR"I. The Hebrew of that roughly translates to *Godly Rabbi Isaac*. Why is he called Godly, and many other great rabbis are not?

Related: [Why refer to Isaac Luria as the Arizal, and not Arizatzal?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/11951/1059)

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure the word means 'Godly' in the sense you are taking it. You seem to be taking in in the sense of 'the one similar to God,' while I think it might be meant to be taken as 'the God expert,' which would explain why the term is exclusively applied to him.

Comment: Even so, then the Ramchal who wrote Derech Hashem could also be a God expert.

Comment: @AdamMosheh "Ri" was already taken by the Ri of Orleans, so the Ari had to come up with another initial to put in there; Ramchal, on the other hand, was not already taken.

Comment: How would that explain its exclusivity?