# What did the Arizal's contemporaries write about him?

Tags: history, mysticism-kabbalah, arizal

Over [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/52452/759), ray posits that the validity of certain schools of Jewish philosophy rests on the [Arizal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isaac_Luria)'s word.

The Arizal was most famous for his teachings in Safed (though he only lived there for two years). At the same time there lived the Mabit, the Beis Yosef, the Alshich and the Radvaz.

Did they comment on the Arizal and/or his teachings?

Comment: It should be noted that ray's position there remains unsourced.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Beis Yosef has a responsum ([Avkat Rochel # 136](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=636&pgnum=242)) addressed to the Arizal, wherein the Arizal is referred to as המקובל האלהי “the godly kabbalist” ([or perhaps האלהי means “theologian”](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/30923/13438)). The Chida cites this responsum from manuscript in his entry for the Arizal in Shem Hagedolim, and has a slightly different wording. There the Arizal is referred to as החכם השלם המקובל “the complete, wise man, kabbalist”.