# List of titles before different Rabbis

Tags: history, words, names, rabbis

It is customary to put many honorific titles before most modern day Rabbis (I've even seen seforim that write Harav Hagaon etc. etc. So-And-So). Many times one sees long lines of adjactives praising the Rabbi being quoted.

Yet, we refer to most of the earlier Rabbis with much less adjectives. I've never heard anyone say Harav Hagaon Rashkebehag Kvod Kdushas Moshe Zatzal when referring to Moshe Rabbeinu.

Is it that we have more respect to our Rabbis than they did in the past?

Comment: See also: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/5720/2 and http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/11951/2

Comment: Could you really have said that Moshe was Rosh Kol Benei HaGolah? There was no Golah!

Comment: The more titles a person needs, the less we are sure of their greatness. Or some quote like that. The more names I see before a rabbi the less respect I assume they have in the greater community, or there would be no need for the honorifics.

Comment: There is a concept (it's first mentioned, as far as I know, by R. Sherira Gaon) that גדול מרבן שמו, the highest accolade that can be given a person is that he doesn't need a title. Hence, he says, the sages of the generations up to Hillel and Shammai didn't have titles; with the decline of Torah knowledge that began then, there developed the hierarchy of titles rabban, rabbi, and rav. (Though that doesn't really answer your question about multiple titles.)

Comment: @Alex, yet we do call them _Avraham avinu_, _Yitzchak avinu_, _Yaakov avinu_, _Yosef hatzadik_, _Moshe rabenu_, _Aharon hakohen_, _David hamelech_, and _Sh'lomo hamelech_, and not _Avraham_, _Yitzchak_, et al.

Comment: @Alex, they were known as Zekeinim.  Hillel HaZakein and Shammai Hazakein.

Comment: Rabbi is an English word.  Rabi, Rebbi, Rebbe, Chacham (Hakham), Gaon, tzurba merabbanan, Rabbeinu, Moreinu, Maran, Zaken, Rosh Yeshivah, and Reish Galuta can all be terms used to refer to Jewish scholars.  This list is obviously not exclusive.

From the New Oxford American Dictionary:
rabbi |ˈrabˌī|
noun ( pl. -bis )
a Jewish scholar or teacher, esp. one who studies or teaches Jewish law.
• a person appointed as a Jewish religious leader.
DERIVATIVES
rabbinate |ˈrabənət; -ˌnāt| noun
ORIGIN late Old English , via ecclesiastical Latin and Greek from Hebrew rabbī ‘my master,’ from ra b ‘master.’

Comment: @msh210: but those are all titles given to them later, not mentioned in Tanach (i.e., their contemporaries didn't call them by those names).

Comment: @Adam: same thing. The cognomen "Hazakein" seems to have been added later, probably to distinguish them from other sages of the same names.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/6309/5

Comment: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20022&st=&pgnum=133

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since nobody answered, I'll just restate my comment.

The more praises and titles a person needs, the more I feel the person is not widely respected.  If they were really well known, they would not need the titles, people would just know who you were talking about when you said "Moshe" or "Hillel."

The reality is your question should be reversed, and you should ask why we shower titles and statements on people who we should be refering to respectfully?  I can not count the number of times I have heard HaGaon HaRav X being used as a way to mock the followers of that Rabbi.

Comment: Good answer.  I didnt realize that the question was a question

Comment: Indeed, a very good answer. Modesty is a Jewish virtue. Showering yourself with various titles to increase your prestige/credibility or what not, is the opposite of modest behavior.

Answer (score 1):

The basis of Jan's answer can be found in the Rambam's introduction to the Mishna.

**הפרק השביעי**, בדרגותיהם כפי מה שעשה המחבר. חלק מעלות האנשים שנזכרו במשנה והם מאה ועשרים ושמונה כמו שהקדמנו לשלש מעלות. **מי שהיה אצלו גדול מאד וברום המעלות קראו בשמו**, כגון הלל, ושמאי, ושמעיה, ואבטליון, מפני גודל מעלתם, **כיון שאי אפשר למצוא כנוי לרומם בו את זכרם, כמו שאין מכנים את הנביאים. ואשר הם אצלו למטה מדרגה זו מכנה אותם בשם רבן**, כגון אמרו רבן גמליאל, רבן יוחנן בן זכאי. **ואשר הם אצלו למטה מדרגה זו מכנה אותם בשם רבי**, כגון אמרו ר' מאיר, ר' יהודה. ומכנה אנשי דרגה זו גם בשם אבא. כגון אמרו אבא שאול. ופעמים משמיט מהם הכינוי דרך אי הקפדה. כגון שמעון אחי עזריה. ואלעזר איש ברתותא. וכלל מי שקראם בשמותיהם דרך גדולה הם אלה, שמעון הצדיק. אנטגנס איש סוכו. יוסי בן יועזר. יוסי בן יוחנן. יוחנן כהן גדול. יהושע בן פרחיה. נתאי הארבלי. חוני המעגל. אליהועיני בן הקף. חנמאל המצרי. יהודה בן טבאי. שמעון בן שטח. עקביה בן מהללאל. שמעיה. ואבטליון. חנן. ואדמון. הלל. ושמאי. נחום הלבלר. וחנניה בן חזקיה בן גרון. בבא בן בוטא. וכל מה שתמצא שנזכר בשמו זולת אלה השמיט הכינוי מהם דרך אי הקפדה.