# When did "Zal" give way to "Zatzal"?

Tags: minhag, history, acronyms

Inspired by [this answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/11952/603) and it's comments.

Early on, it was standard to refer to great Rabbis who had passed away with the appellation "Zal" - *"zichrono/ah livracha "May his/her/their memory be a blessing"* (see [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/6317/603)). Over time, people started using the appellation "Zatzal" - *zecher tzadik livracha "May the memory of this tzaddik be a blessing"* - when talking about great rabbis who have passed away.

When did this trend start? When was the shift made from "Zal" to "Zatzal"?

Comment: in a similar vein: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/5720/meforshim-nicknames

Comment: And when was it made to ZTZVLLZZLLKVKLZLZKLKKLK"L?

Comment: I would claim the opposite. After all it was Shlomo HaMelech who already coined the phrase zt"l in  זֵכֶר צַדִּיק לִבְרָכָה in משלי Ch 10:7. http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/t/t2810.htm - where does z"l come from?

Comment: @DannySchoemann: Shlomo HaMelech wasn't saying it on anyone though. Although that may an answer. Z"l is "Zecher L'Bracha". Maybe originally it was only used for Tzadikim, in reference to the Passuk. Once people started using it for anyone who wasn't a Rasha (not just a Tzaddik), people started using Zatzal to show they were speaking about a Tzaddik, and not just a Rasha.

Comment: (Actually, I was taught that Z"l is "Zichrono/Zichrona Livracha")

Comment: @DannySchoemann: Correct. My bad. I had it right in the question.

Comment: Similar: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/30470

Answer (score 3):

Some speculation inspired by the comments to this question.

The verse in Mishlei ([10:7](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt2810.htm#7)) says:

> זֵכֶר צַדִּיק, לִבְרָכָה; וְשֵׁם רְשָׁעִים יִרְקָב.‏
>
> The memory of the righteous shall be for a blessing; but the name of the wicked shall rot.

Rashi [explains](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16381/showrashi/true#v7):

> **The mention of a righteous man is for a blessing:** Whoever mentions a righteous man blesses him.
> **but the name of the wicked shall rot:** Decay develops in their name, for no one wishes to mention his [the wicked man’s] name, and it is automatically forgotten.

Initially, people would use *Zichrono LeBracha*, *"May his memory be for a blessing"*, when referencing a Tzaddik who had passed away. Over time (perhaps because nobody wanted to imply that the deceased was wicked), this evolved into saying it for any person who was not a Rasha.

Once this became prevalent, the need was felt to distinguish the Righteous from the Ordinary, and *Zecher Tzadik LeBracha* was born.