# What does שליט"א stand for?

Tags: history, hebrew, grammar-dikduk, rabbis

I thought that שליט"א came from the Aramaic word שליט (Ruler). But a Rabbi I told this to, pointed out that שליט"א is always written as with " , in the Middle so each the letters must stand for something. (But he didn't know what it stood for.)
Does anyone know If and What does שליט"א does stand for?

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/97314/origin-and-meaning-of-the-honorific-shlita https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/30470/%d7%a9%d7%9c%d7%99%d7%98-%d7%90-only-for-certain-people https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/6309/abbreviations-before-after-names

Comment: @ Alex Thank you for the link

Comment: שיפול לבור י' טפחים אמן is the humorous version.

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/119717/what-does-%d7%a9%d7%9c%d7%99%d7%98%d7%90-stand-for

Answer (score 9):

For what it's worth, the Otzar of Roshei Teivot on Bar Ilan lists both שיחיה לאורך ימים טובים ארוכים and שיחיה לאורך ימים טובים אמן. I prefer the latter, because the former is redundant, as pointed out by @DoubleAA in a [comment above](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/119717/what-does-%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%98%D7%90-stand-for/119718?noredirect=1#comment396262_119718).

However, the best evidence one could have in this situation is to see if this phrase was ever written out in full form. In searching for various forms of the expanded words, I was unable to find any one who wished another person "שיחיה לאורך ימים טובים ארוכים" in a full written form. I was, however, able to find a significant authority who blessed people "שיחיה לאורך ימים טובים אמן" in full written form. Rav David Zvi Hoffman (Shu"t Melamed Leho'il 2:127) writes:

ואחר כל אלה הדברים גם אני מסכים עם כבוד מעלתו שמצוה על קהלתו להבדל ולהפרש מחברת המדיחים האלה ולהשתדל לקנות בית הקברות מיוחד בעד היראים **שיחיו לארך ימים טובים אמן.**

I feel this is the closest you can get to a "proof" or "source" one way or another, and I leave it in the hands of the voters.

See also https://judaism.codidact.com/posts/280012 with the comments there.

Comment: RDZH lived about 150 years ago, but the acronym has been around for centuries. An earlier source would be better...

Comment: I agree, but I couldn't find one. As an aside, how many centuries has it been popularly used for, as opposed to other blessings (such as שיחיה לאורך ימים שונים), or other similar phrases? @DoubleAA

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/30999/759

Comment: Additionally, the Or Zarua' (1:774) and the Maharam of Rothenburg (many instances) used שיחיה לאורך ימים in their 13th century responsa.

Comment: @Fred I saw those, but none of them had the concluding ט"א.

Comment: @רבות מחשבות A belated Thank You! Is in order. Just as you said I found שליט"א it spelled out in R. Dovid Hoffman's תשובות. This is the best proof.

Comment: @Sochaz thanks, glad to hear it answered your question!

Comment: Double AA- While I appreciate your efforts in finding the link, unfortunately not only didn't it help answer the question. (The link was supposedly used to prove that  in the Times of the Levush (& Rama) שליט"א was used to refer to a living son or father on a שטר) But in fact looking into.     לבוש עיר שושן - חלק ה – סימן. מט,סיוף ז. not only does not spell out the acronym, but he uses the acronym שלי"ט- without the א.   But I do thank you for trying to help.

Answer (score 5):

שיחיה לאורך ימים טובים ארוכים

Who should live for a length of many good days.

Comment: לאורך ארוכים?? seems quite redundant

Comment: Yeah, I had that observation when I was trying to translate it. Maybe it's something along the lines of וְאַבְרָהָ֣ם זָקֵ֔ן בָּ֖א בַּיָּמִ֑ים.

Comment: why would an acronym have a hey if the final word begins with an aleph?

Comment: @rosends Have never seen this with a *heh*. Refer https://he.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%98%22%D7%90

Comment: @rosends I apologize I originally wrote it with a "ה".  Looking over the Answers I saw your appropriate question and Edited my own question to שליט"א

Comment: @ The GRAPKE I incorrectly spelled שליט"א using a ה, which I've since corrected. Alex Answerd quoting someone on Mi Yodea ( who spelled out a few dozen common Rabbinic Jewish '"acronyms",  שליט"א included.  But the Author gave no source.  He gave the same explaination that you did; However,  Double AA has a good quiestion. But I לאורך ארוכים is a double לשון, whereas בָּ֖א בַּיָּמִ֑ים means (Advanced -בא) (in years-בימים).

Comment: @Sochacz There is an interpretation of that *passuk* that Avraham literally came with his days. Since each day was lived to the full, he came with a full complement of his days. I.e. the day is only as long as you have lived it to the full.

Comment: @The GRAPKE I'm sorry. I like  לאורך יומים שיחיה טובים ארוכיםMy real question is do you recall were you heard this acronym for שליט"א?

Comment: @The GRAPKE You 're explaination would also explain why we don't use שליט"א for a living person.  I'm voting it up.  (I just wish you had a Mesorah or Mikor for it)

Comment: @Sochacz You mean for a non-living person?

Comment: @ The GRAPKE. Yes. I also understand your reference to Avraham IE. That the Bracha given in שליט"א is that The ת"ח upon whom the honorific (שליט"א) is used should use everyday to its fullest.

Comment: @Sochacz Yes, it is a mussar zog

Comment: Pretty sure the א at the end stands for אמן

Comment: @shimon I've heard that as well. At the very least it solves since of the redundancy.

Comment: @Shimon bM That's interesting. Do you have a written Source for that, I'd be very grateful if you could tell me where you got that from. Thanx!

Comment: @רבות מחשבות Thank you, do you have a מיקר for that, is it written down anywhere?

Comment: @Sochacz as I have written elsewhere, it's virtually impossible to have some sort of authoritative source for something like this. Even if someone wrote it in some book of Rashei Teivot, it's still just that author's opinion. Nevertheless, I'll try to post an answer below:

Comment: A better translation of, "שיחיה לאורך ימים טובים ארוכים", would be, "who will live for (meaning, according to) Your Light, days of good length. This means, who will live "according to the commandments of the Torah..." See the commentary of the Ba'al HaTurim to Bereshit 1:4 for details.

Comment: @yaacov that should be a comment or another post, since it is another pronunciation and meaning of the words (which I have never heard anyone use, tbh).

Comment: @yaakov except that The Grapke responded above to DoubleAA, which is why I assume this reading (which may have merit), is not what he intended. I'm sure if you make reference to this post in your own answer, it won't be taken badly.

Comment: ארוכּים or אמן.

Answer (score 1):

The expansion by theGRAPKE for שליט״א as:

**ש**יחיה **ל**אורך **י**מים **ט**ובים **א**רוכים

is traditionally translated as:

that (they, *meaning the person named preceding the abbreviation*) will live for (meaning, *according to*) **Your Light** (*Your light*, means *G-d's light*), good, long days.

לאורך is actually a noun with a *Kametz* beneath the Lamed. This implies that the word for *Your Light* is preceded by the *Indicative Heh*, as in האור. It is the known light mentioned in the Torah in Bereshit 1:4 which says:

> וַיַּ֧רְא אֱלֹהִ֛ים אֶת־**הָא֖וֹר** כִּי־ט֑וֹב וַיַּבְדֵּ֣ל אֱלֹהִ֔ים בֵּ֥ין הָא֖וֹר וּבֵ֥ין הַחֹֽשֶׁךְ׃

In this posuk, it also associates this light specifically with the concept of *good*. (וַיַּ֧רְא אֱלֹהִ֛ים אֶת־הָא֖וֹר **כִּי־ט֑וֹב**). That טוב (*good*) is actually a reference to another of G-d's names (אהוה), which has an equivalent numerical value.

And this follows the explanation of the commentary, Ba'al HaTurim HaShalem there which states:

**את האור.** בגימטריא **בתורה** ועולה מנין **תרי״ג**

That *The Light* (את-האור) has the numerical value to *in the Torah* (בתורה) and adds up to 613 (The number of commandments given to the Jewish people by G-d).

That *the light* being referred to in this utterance from Creation is the enumeration of the 613 commandments contained within the Torah. It is through fulfilling them that G-d's presence is revealed in the world (in the entire universe).

That the commandments are called paths (נתיבות), similar to the expression used for the first section to Shulchan Aruch, namely אורח חיים, the Way (or Path) of Life.

And this is in keeping with what we recite when returning the Sefer Torah to the Aron Kodesh after reading it:

וכל נתיבותיה שלום, **ארך ימים** בימינה כו׳

All its (the Torah's) paths are peace, ***length of days*** pertains to its right, etc.

It should also be pointed out that while in the phrase said when returning the Torah, the word length (ארך) is a noun, in the phrase brought by theGRAPKE it is used as an adjective, modifying the noun, days (ימים). It is for this reason that it appears in number agreement as ימים טובים **ארוכים**.

This plural form of טוב indicates the various expansions of G-d's name (אהוה), namely the expansions of 144, 153 and 155 which all pertain to specific concepts within G-d's creation.

Comment: Thanks for posting here. However, wouldn't it make more sense to write שיחיה לאור ה' ימים טובים ארוכים? Isn't Shlit"a used to address an individual directly, in which case "you" would be the person you are addressing?

Answer (score 0):

Sheyikhye Le'orech Yamim Tovim Amen (per wikipedia: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honorifics_in_Judaism#:~:text='Shlit%22a'%20(or,someone's%20child's%20Rebbe%20(teacher).)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honorifics_in_Judaism#:%7E:text=%27Shlit%22a%27%20(or,someone%27s%20child%27s%20Rebbe%20(teacher).))

Answer (score 0):

As a child until today I've always
read it as:
**ש**יחי' **לי**מים **ט**ובים **א**רוכים

...which would clarify the above confusion.

Comment: Why does one of the words get two letters of the acronym?

Comment: So you don’t follow the traditional teaching concerning Notarikon that each letter in the abbreviation represents a single word?

Comment: Well, anytime there is a modifier To, from, etc. The first letter doesn't count and can be added to the roshei teivos. I've seen this many times.

Comment: ...and I did mention this as a childish idiom kept into adulthood.

Answer (score -1):

The aramaic etymology is correct but because of the folk etymology (as other have given) it is almost universally spelled with ".

Comment: Hi How do you know this?

Comment: A very good indication is that no one ever wrote it out in full before it became popular, no one is certain for what it stands (all suggestions are awkward and obviously backformed), and it looks exactly like a completely standard Aramaic honorific.

Comment: I would add also that the Rema is apparently the first to use שלי"ט as a Hebrew honorific (no א in the first edition). However, the first printing is posthumous (1578) and I don't know of anything in his own hand. On the other hand, his contemporary Azariah de Rossi refers to a couple of people as שליט in the Meor Einayim, in manuscript, including the Rema, and never uses a gershayim.