# Was the term shlita (שליטא) always reserved for rabbis or prominent people? If so, why? If not, how come it became limited in this way?

Tags: minhag, hebrew

"Shlita" is customarily added to the name of a living rabbi or leader, either in addressing or speaking/writing about him. It is often written as an acronym, as in "shlit"a" or שליט׳׳א. As an acronym, it's a blessing for a long life. Why, then, should its usage be limited to rabbanim (other than the fact that the non-acronym form (שליטא) means "leader")? Is it improper to use it for someone who is not a leader?

A related question: [What does שליט"א stand for?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/119717/what-does-%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%98%D7%90-stand-for)

Comment: Hi user5829 shlita, see the duplicate question