# Yemach Shemo and Zichrono Livracha

Tags: minhag

Why don't we say Yemach Shemo after people like Vespasian and other people who did bad things to the Jews many years ago?  Why do we only say it after relatively recent Reshaim, e.g. Hitler.

Similarly, why don't we say Zichrono Livracha after Abaye and Rava, and just after more recent Tzaddikim?  It is noteworthy that Chassidim ofter write a longer version of it after former Rebbes.

Comment: one of the prime examples of yemach shemo is not recent

Comment: perhaps you mean zechuto yagen aleynu

Comment: Can you [edit] to source that this is indeed what "we" do? Perhaps also better define "we" as not everyone does the same thing always.

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/17723/759

Comment: No saying zichrono livracha after Abaye and Rava? What about the Ari Zal?

Comment: @Danno Ok, שר"י

Comment: @ezra they lived about 1000 years apart

Comment: BTW the construct form of Zekher is Zikhro.

Comment: The Yerushalmi has ז״ל for Eliyahu [1](http://www.sefaria.org/Jerusalem_Talmud_Berakhot.64a.3/he/Mechon_Mamre_Talmud_Yerushalmi?lang=bi) [2](http://www.sefaria.org/Jerusalem_Talmud_Shabbat.8b.1/he/Mechon_Mamre_Talmud_Yerushalmi?lang=bi) [3](http://www.sefaria.org/Jerusalem_Talmud_Shabbat.9b/he/Mechon_Mamre_Talmud_Yerushalmi?lang=bi). But that's no information on what is currently done.